# How to allow an external IP to connect to an Oracle Database in OCI

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle19c, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

We have an Oracle Database on the OCI. We need to allow an external IP from one of our customers to connect directly to it via a connection string (like external-ip:1521/servicename) but we can't figure out how.

We tried allowing the external IP through our VCN and connecting through that url that goes something like `db-name.sub123455.vcnname.oraclevcn.com` and the service name `sname.sub12345.vcnname.oraclevcn.com`. Our corporate network has some kind of rule or configuration that lets us connect to the DB by using a local looking ip like 10.0.10.1 but I don't know exactly what is doing, and if it's necessary to allow a single external IP to connect to the DB.